# PHP how to make a relationship between two tables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm an absolute beginner to PHP and MySQL. I have a pre-coded project which I currently making personalised modifications.

Following are the screenshots of my database.

[image: Products]

[image: Categories]

From the front-end I need to list all categories, and all respective products under each category.

[image: Categories]

I can't figure out how to bind two different tables and show products related to each category.

Comment: You will be needing the [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) syntax for that

Comment: join with manyToOne relation (one gategorie have one or more products).

Answer (score 0):

you need manyToOne relation with product table and categorie table:
one categorie have one or more product:
you need join between tow table:categorie(id_categorie,name,etc..),product(id_product,name,etc...,#id_categorie)id_categorie:foreignKey in product table.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL table should have foreign keys. In PHP just take all categories and all products. When you list a category just list all of product with have categor_id equal to id of category with you listed:

categories: ID, name
peroducts: ID, name, category_id

List:
category 1
- products: all with have product.category_id = category.id

Comment: I understand the approach now, was wondering how can I get this done with PHP